# What is entropy starvation

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I was lost when reading

> "Knowing how Linux behaves during entropy starvation (and being able to find the cause) allows us to efficiently use our server hardware."

in a [blog](http://www.palantir.com/2013/01/server-side-quality-engineering-exploring-software-from-the-inside-out/). Then I wikied the meaning of '[entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29)' in the context of linux. But still, not clear what "entropy starvation' is and the meaning of the sentence quoted above.

Comment: Put quotes around your Google Search, like this: https://www.google.com/search?q="Entropy+starvation"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some applications, notably cryptography, need random data. In cryptography, it is very important that the data be truly random, or at least unpredictable (even in part) to any attacker.

To supply this data, a system keeps a [pool of random data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28computing%29), called entropy, that it collects from various sources of randomness on the system: Precise timing of events that might be somewhat random (keys pressed by users, interrupts from external devices), noise on a microphone, or, on some processors, dedicated hardware for generating random values. The incoming somewhat-random data is mixed together to produce better quality entropy.

These sources of randomness can only supply data at certain rates. If a system is used to do a lot of work that needs random data, it can use up more random data than is available. Then software that wants random data has to wait for more to be generated or it has to accept lower-quality data. This is called entropy starvation or entropy depletion.

Comment: This is inaccurate. It’s what some of the Linux maintainers believe, but they are wrong, as indicated by every other operating system (and linux itself, if you use the correct api) doing it differently https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/

Comment: @Glyph: (a) Your comment does not state what is inaccurate. (b) The article you link to seems to criticize /dev/random, so maybe that is what you allude to. However, this answer does not speak to the quality of /dev/random or to its merits relative to /dev/urandom. It merely explains how it works, particularly in relation to the question about entropy starvation. This answer does not assert it is an ideal solution or is better or worse than /dev/urandom for any specific purposes.

Comment: (c) The article you link to does not give clear reasons to believe its claims. Two articles it links to are not about quality problems in /dev/random. Indeed, the article’s only complaint about /dev/random may be that using it requires accepting a delay on occasion. That is irrelevant to this question and answer.

Comment: What's inaccurate is the claim that "it can use up more random data than is available".  Entropy does not get "used up"; this is a misunderstanding of how CSPRNGs work. Re-seeding periodically is a good idea to defend against the possibility that secret internal state might get leaked, but generating more random numbers from a cryptographic stream does not in any way "reduce" entropy. Here's a more specific explanation: https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Comment: Importantly, Linux itself has been changed so this no longer occurs, because the behavior of `/dev/random` has been changed to not block except in the early stages of the boot process where no seeding has occurred at all: https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-5.6-Random-Rework

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to correct the answer by changing "a system" to "versions of the Linux kernel before 5.6" and "If a system is used to do a lot of work that needs random data, it can use up more random data than is available, it can reduce the Linux kernel's entropy heuristic, waiting until more random data is collected. On other operating systems and more recent versions of linux, more academically accepted randomness generation techniques such as Yarrow or Fortuna do not have this issue"

Comment: @Glyph: The article you link to does not say the entropy counting in /dev/random is incorrect or that entropy does not get used up. It says urandom is sufficient for most purposes. It does not say entropy does not run low, just that it is not an issue for most purposes because urandom is good enough. The article admits that /dev/random serves in certain situations where /dev/urandom cannot. It merely says those situations are more limited than most people use /dev/random for. So it is not relevant to this question, which is about what entropy starvation is and not about which device to prefer.

Comment: @Glyph: That entropy runs low is a mathematical fact. If any generator is seeded with n bits, random or otherwise, there are 2^n possible inputs and hence 2^n possible output sequences. If m > n bits are drawn from it, the m bits cannot be independent because not all 2^m combinations of m bits are possible; there are at most 2^n possible outputs. Therefore there must be correlations among the m bits. The article you link to does not deny this; it merely asserts this is not a concern for most uses of cryptographic randomness, because they do not need true randomness.

Comment: What you are describing is entropy in a system which draws a maximally surprising sequence of bits from something like a black-body radiation source, then doles those bits out to applications, blocking when it needs more. That would indeed "run out". This is not how the Linux RNG has ever worked, however; even in its original implementation it merely maintained heuristics. Since 2016, it has used a CSPRNG for its random generation, and since 2020 it hasn't even maintained its weird heuristic estimate.

Comment: "Entropy" in information theory describes the unpredictability of the observed outputs. *If* the seeding data is secret, and the distribution of bits is even (it is, and they are) then from the application's point of view, the information-theoretic entropy generated by a CSPRNG is equivalent to the "entropy" generated by network card interrupt timings modulo some small value, or whatever seeding data is generated from.

Comment: If you posit that the seed data in the kernel is known, then you could *also* posit that the "seed data" of the physical world (i.e. the physical characteristics of the network card, the likely nearby sources of audio waveforms, some flaw in RDRAND that allows you to predict its output) is known, and make its outputs equally predictable.

Comment: This isn't even purely a theoretical concern. Things like TEMPEST attacks really do observe the electromechanical environment of target systems to exfiltrate secrets, so there are definitely ways to observe the supposedly "random" data that the system is collecting, making it entirely non-random for an attacker.

Comment: For a description of why the entropy counting originally used by the Linux kernel *was* incorrect, have a look at DJB's paper from 2014 described in the history of the kernel's RNG here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux

Comment: @Glyph: DJB’s paper does not say there is anything wrong with the concept of counting entropy. It merely says the implementation is subject to an attack, in theory. It does not say the entropy counting originally used by the Linux kernel (or since) was incorrect.

Comment: He does not say that directly, because he assumes that his readers understand this basic fact of cryptography. He does say: "The Linux /dev/urandom manual page claims that without new entropy the user is "theoretically vulnerable to a cryptographic attack", but (as I've mentioned in various venues) this is a ludicrous argument". So entropy counting is a "ludicrous argument", not "incorrect". If there is a distinction here, it is one without a difference.

Answer (score 10):

This phrase is meaningless, and thankfully, outdated and irrelevant.  It is based on a persistent misunderstanding that Theodore Ts'o, the maintainer of the Linux entropy subsystem, had about the way that physical noise gathering corresponds to cryptographic security of the unpredictability of hash outputs.

To quote [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Linux):

> In 2020, the Linux kernel version 5.6 /dev/random only blocks when the CPRNG hasn't initialized. Once initialized, /dev/random and /dev/urandom behave the same

So, you do not need to know or care about the confusing history of the concept of "entropy starvation" since 2020.

Over the years, various people have attempted to correct this misconception; these are the two most prominent articles:

- https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/
- https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/